# How to split string value into multiple values

Tags: java

I have one `String` value which I am getting from one of svo,
i.e. `String reply=svo.getReplies();`

The output that I am getting is like -->  `"1:true,2:false,3:true,4:false,5:false,6:false"`

Now what I want is to separate storage of the reply and store all replies in new variables for every reply. For example:

```
String firstVal= "true";
String secondeVal= "false";
// ... and so on.
```

How can I do it?

Comment: first split on comma and then split each one of them on colon and store them in a variable

Comment: You need to put it on variables like `firstVal` and `secondVal` directly or can be used other structures like arrays or maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `Map` from this string. And then use that map as you need.
For example: `String firstVal = map.get(1);`

```
String s1 = "1:true,2:false,3:true,4:false,5:false,6:false";

Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String s : s1.split(",")){
        map.put(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(":"))), s.substring(s.indexOf(":")+1));
    }

for (Integer key : map.keySet()) System.out.println(key + " " + map.get(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in java unless you use a for loop, how ever you can use `String#split(",");` to split the string into a String[]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some example code for you, using the Map Interface:

```
public class splitstringexample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String reply = "1:true,2:false,3:true,4:false,5:false,6:false";
        Map<String, Boolean> example = splitString(reply);

        for (String name: example.keySet()){
            String key =name.toString();
            String value = example.get(name).toString();  
            System.out.println(key + " " + value);  
        } 
    }
    public static Map<String,Boolean> splitString(String reply){
        Map<String, Boolean> mapping = new HashMap<>();
        String[] mappings = reply.split(",");
        for(String s : mappings) {
            String[] parts = s.split(":");
            mapping.put(parts[0],Boolean.parseBoolean(parts[1]));
        }
        return mapping;
    }
}
```

With a map object you can then use `mapObject.get(<identifier>)` to access the corresponding boolean value. In your case `mapObject.get("1")` would return `true`,`mapObject.get("2") false` and so on

Comment: Thanks @tistorm for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a regular expression :

```
//Compile the regular expression patern
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+):(true|false)+?") ; 
//match the patern over your input
Matcher m = p.matcher("1:true,2:false,3:true,4:false,5:false,6:false") ; 

// iterate over results (for exemple add them to a map)
Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
while (m.find()) {
    // here m.group(1) contains the digit, and m.group(2) contains the value ("true" or "false")
    map.put(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)), Boolean.parseBoolean(m.group(2)));
    System.out.println(m.group(2)) ;
}
```

More informations abour regular expressions syntax can be found here :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

EDIT : changed the list to a Map

Answer (score 0):

Using `replaceFirst` and  spliting it with regex: `,\\d:` and store each value in an array

```
String str = "1:true,2:false,3:true,4:false,5:false,6:false".replaceFirst("1:","");
String[] strArray =  str.split(",\\d:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
```

output

```
[true, false, true, false, false, false]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Pattern` and `Stream` over the matching results applied to the `String` returrned by `svo.getReplies()`:

```
String input = "1:true,2:false,3:true,4:false,5:false,6:false";
String[] result = Pattern.compile("(true|false)")
  .matcher(input)
  .results()
  .map(MatchResult::group)
  .toArray(String[]::new);
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result)); // [true, false, true, false, false, false]
 String firstVal = result[0]; // true
 String secondVal = result[1]; // false
 // ...
```